# Index of row number minus row index of last non-zero element in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

Using Python, I am trying to compute the interval between non-zero values in a dataframe, and input the interval as an integer in a dataframe. The following is a sample dataset:

| Week | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| Two | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Three | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Four | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| Five | 4 | 1 | 0 |

The following are the conditions for the output:

1. If value == 0, return 0
2. If value != 0, row number of value minus the last non-zero element

The desired output is this:

| Week | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Two | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Three | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Four | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Five | 2 | 3 | 0 |

I have tried using for loop and if else, but have always met with some form of error as my python proficiency level isn't high. Hope for some guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am trying to find the interval (e.g. no of weeks) between each row and the row of the last non-zero element before it. For instance, for Column Y:  In the first row, as Week One is the first week, it does not have any interval. Hence, the output is 0. In the second row, as the last non-zero element is in the preceding week, output is 2-1=1. In the third row, as the value is zero, the output is zero. Same as the fourth row. In the fifth row, as the last non-zero element is in Week Two, the output is 5-2=3.

Comment: So if I understand it right, the columns are independent?

Comment: That's right. The columns are independent.